# Specify legend position in a plot

Tags: legending

I would like to place the legend inside the plot frame. I have been doing a search in the documentation but only found option

```
ChartLegends -> Placed[{"label", {Center}]
```

Other options, such as `Up`, `Bottom`, `Right`, place the label outside.

How can I put the legend inside the frame of the plot?

Comment: You refer to "plot" but the only code provided applies to a "chart". You might want to clarify what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Legended[
 BarChart[{{4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}},
  ChartStyle -> {"Pastel", None}],
 Placed[
  SwatchLegend[
   ColorData["Pastel", #] & /@ {0, 1},
   {"Group A", "Group B"}],
  {0.8, 0.8}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** More simply,

```
BarChart[{{4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}},
 ChartStyle -> {"Pastel", None},
 ChartLegends -> Placed[
   {{"Group A", "Group B"}, None},
   {0.8, 0.8}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** Using [`SmoothHistogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothHistogram.html)

```
SmoothHistogram[
 Table[
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[c, 1], 500],
  {c, 0, 5}],
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Range[0, 5], {0.9, 0.7}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. I also wanted to ask the same question but using `PlotLegends` option of `SmoothHistogram`. I have tried this solution but does not work with `PlotLegends`. Regards.

Comment: See `EDIT 2`. When asking a question, you need to post code for minimal working example that demonstrates issue that you are having.

Comment: Thank you, the solutions have solved this problem. I use `PlotTheme -> "Scientific", ChartStyle -> 96, ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[None], Opacity[0.25]]`in the Histogram then I have put `Placed[ SwatchLegend[96, {"No stigmergy", "FPS"}], {0.9, 0.8}]`in my code but the color of the legend looks darker (intense) than the plot lines. Do you know how I could match both, plot lines and legend colors?. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user1993416 - Post a new question that includes the actual data and code that you are using and the issue that you want resolved.

Comment: @BobHanlon, very nice!  What if we want a framed legend, e.g.                ```legend =  Placed[LineLegend[l, LegendFunction -> "Frame"], {.6, .4}];``` with white space, rather than gridlines (needed for plot) within the legend frame?

Comment: @mjw - do not ask questions in comments. Post a question with your code for a complete minimal working example that shows the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @BobHanlon, okay, will do ...