# Include the legend inside the plot but was failed

Tags: plotting, legending

I'm trying to include the legends inside the frame of the plot like this

[image: hehe]

Here is my Attempt:

```
ListPlot[{{2, 5, 2, 8, 6, 8, 3}, {1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {"\[SixPointedStar]", 15}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Green}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed["line1", "line2", 
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0] &)], Frame -> True]
```

My references:

1. [specify-legend-position-in-a-plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141737/specify-legend-position-in-a-plot)
2. [plotting-legends-matching-with-plots-inside-the-show-graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173911/plotting-legends-matching-with-plots-inside-the-show-graph)
3. [placing-plot-legends-inside-a-plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212046/placing-plot-legends-inside-a-plot)
4. [place-a-legend-inside-a-plot.](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/legends/place-a-legend-inside-a-plot.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Space for the legend is available at the upper left

```
ListPlot[{
  {2, 5, 2, 8, 6, 8, 3},
  {1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3}},
 PlotMarkers -> {"✶", 15},
 Joined -> True,
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Green},
 PlotLegends ->
  Placed[
   LineLegend[{"line1", "line2"},
    LegendFunction -> "Frame"],
   {.15, .8}],
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

To locate legend at upper right you must change the [`PlotRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html)

```
ListPlot[{
  {2, 5, 2, 8, 6, 8, 3},
  {1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3}},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 9}, {0, 9}},
 PlotMarkers -> {"✶", 15},
 Joined -> True,
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Green},
 PlotLegends ->
  Placed[
   LineLegend[{"line1", "line2"},
    LegendFunction -> "Frame"],
   {.85, .8}],
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You did not put any location for `Placed`

```
ListPlot[{{2, 5, 2, 8, 6, 8, 3}, {1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {"\[SixPointedStar]", 15}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Green}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"line1", "line2"}, 
 LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0] &)], {0.1, 0.5}], 
Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Often these graphics commands are a bit obscure and one has to try. Is the following approx. what you are looking for?:

```
ListPlot[{{2, 5, 2, 8, 6, 8, 3}, {1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {"\[SixPointedStar]", 15}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Green}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"line1", "line2"}, 
    LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.85, 0.8}], Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, All}]
```

[image]